Can you cast a spell-like ability into a Ring of Spell Storing?
A ring of spell storing stores a certain number of spell levels. It also allows you to cast spells from scrolls into it.
Spell-like abilities are sometimes like spells, sometimes not. They (usually) have spell levels, so mechanically it would work fine.
So, can you put a spell-like ability into a ring of spell storing? More specifically, can you put warlock invocations inside? Seems like this would make personal invocations that last 24 hours stronger than intended, since you could give them to the whole party without using daily resources (let's assume you can cast personal spells into the ring, even if it is not a part of you and possibly outside the range of "personal").

No, spell-like abilities are not spells, and spells are what spell-storing stores. The term “spell-like” can be misleading: spell-like abilities are usually “like” some spell, so a fireball spell-like ability is “like” the spell fireball—except in all the ways that spell-like abilities are different from spells. The rules for spell-like ability are quite different from those for spell, and “spell” as a term refers only to spells.
You need to see “spell or spell-like ability” to officially be able use a spell-like ability. There are a fair few cases where the lack of that may seem like an oversight or error, but for the reasons you note, spell-storing is not one of them.
